# Openlayers 3 Replace a failed tile

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, tile

We are running Open Layers 3.15.
Sometimes we get a dropped or failed tile.
Currently it displays nothing, (which can be confusing for our users) so  we'd like to replace this with a tile that says 'no data' or something.
I've tried picking up the event and replacing the source of the tile eg

```
            source.on('tileloaderror', function(){
               source.setUrl('./images/map/failureTile.png');
            });
```

but the problem with this is, instead of doing this on 1 tile, it does it for the entire layer, we don't want that.

Anyone know how we can do this for just the tile that failed and not the entire layer?

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of layer you create? E.g. Tile, Image, etc. As a clarification, `source.setUrl` is supposed to have placeholders for coordinates. These placeholders are replaced by actual values before the request to the instantiated URL is made.

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm creating an ol.layer.Tile

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018, but for someone who may need this. Tested on v5.3.0

```
source.on('tileloaderror', function (event) {
  var tileLoadFunction = function (imageTile, src) {
    imageTile.getImage().src = './images/map/failureTile.png';
  };
  if (event.tile.tileLoadFunction_ != tileLoadFunction) {
    event.tile.tileLoadFunction_ = tileLoadFunction;
    event.tile.load();
  }
});
```

This code relys on private function `event.tile.tileLoadFunction_` is exposed.

Unfortunately xnakos' answer doesn't work on v5.3.0 because the `event.tile.getImage()` has been replaced with 1x1 canvas image by internal error handler.

Also noted, changing `event.tile.src_` directly, seems to be an option, but it doesn't work either because of cache key or something.

Answer (score 0):

A tile which failed to load should have a distinct class (.olImageLoadError). You can define a CSS rule not show these items.

```
.olImageLoadError { 
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what I would like to do, is replace the tile that failed with one of our own (that is a grey tile with 'no data' written in it).  Of course if there is a way to do this via css, that would also work for us.

Comment: the class should be on an image item. you can force the source instead of the display.

Comment: I think this is an openlayers 2 feature, not a openlayers 3 one, that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
source.on('tileloaderror', function(event) {
    event.tile.getImage().src = './images/map/failureTile.png';
});
```

You need the `event` parameter, that can get you the tile that failed, so that you can change the tile's image.

Warning: I tested the code above using `tileloadend` instead of `tileloaderror`, because my tiles never fail on me. :) I used a simulated failure rate using `Math.random()` and some random tiles were replaced by the image specified. I cannot think of a reason the code above would not work. If you verify it works, I will remove this warning from my answer. I tested it on OpenLayers 3.14.2 and on an OSM source.

Comment: Thank you I did try that, and it does change the url, but doesn't reload the image.